# Jquery Highcharts is not loading when using with common function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working with jquery HighCharts. I want to create a common function to develop multiple charts of same type.
To achieve this goad I created a function as follow -

```
function generateGraph(data) {
   var dates = new Array();        
   var startDate  =  "";
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {        
      dates[i] = data[i].date;         
   }
    var productInsight = _comm.getProductInsightArray();
    var productInsight_Array = new Array();
    $.each(productInsight, function(key, value) {
        productInsight_Array.push(key);
    });

   if(dates.length > 0) {
      startDate = dates[0].split("/");
   }

   intervals = 24 *3600 * 1000; //one day       
   var title = $("#DateSearch_analytics_Similar_Stores1").val(); 
   var color = ['#000000', '#FFFFFF', '#000080', '#0000FF', '#808080'];
   var containers =['container1', 'container2','container3','container4', 'container5', 'container6', 'container7', 'container8', 'container9'];

 for(var j=0; j<containers.length; j++)
 {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            renderTo: containers[j],
            type: 'line',
        },
        title: {
           text:   title
        },
        subtitle: {
           text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
               'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
               'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime',
           tickInterval: intervals,      
        },

        series: []  
    });

    for(var i=0; i < productInsight_Array.length; i++) {
            var fillData = new Array();
            var counter = 0;
            var productValue = document.getElementById('product-nm').value;
            $.each(dates, function() {
                fillData[counter] = _comm.randomNumberFromRange(_randomNumberStartRange, _randomNumberEndRange);
                counter++;
            });
            chart.addSeries({
                name: productInsight_Array[i],
                type: 'line',
                color: color[i],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(startDate[2], startDate[0] - 1, startDate[1]),
                pointInterval: intervals,
                data: fillData,

            });
         }

    $("text:contains('Highcharts.com')").css("display", "none");
  }
}
```

Its working fine and developing charts on window load and button click. I am saving these graph in 9 container but this script is not loading graph in 3rd container and when I remove 3rd container than its not loading in fourth and so on. But it works fine when I call this function on button click in place of document load.

I am little surprised why its happing, As a common function creting all graphs.

I need your help! :(

Thanks

Comment: Show how you use `generateGraph` function.

Comment: Are there no exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle, otherwise it’s hard to guess what exactly fails…

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when load the function your markup doesnt exists. For this reason when you click the button works ok. When the button is visible, all markup is already loaded.

Review your load order.

Also aside comment: put this in your chart declaration:

```
credits: {
   enabled: false
}
```

To not show the credits message: "Highcharts.com".
[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/credits/enabled-false/)

Comment: Can you explain why it’s specifically not loading in the third container though?

Comment: A fiddle with the exact problem can be of help here, in order to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Agreed. But I’m not the OP, I’m just asking questions.

Comment: I have tried it credits: false  in code like this

chart.addSeries({
                name: productInsight_Array[i],
                type: 'line',
                color: color[i],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(startDate[2], startDate[0] - 1, startDate[1]),
                pointInterval: intervals,
                data: fillData,
                credits: false,
            });
   
   
I have also tried it by using here

 chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            renderTo: containers[j],
            type: 'line',
   credits: false,
        },
  
But its is still not loaded at on load

Comment: Credits should be in global options json, not in chart object. [Example](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits)